# What name is given to a value such as this?

Tags: stocks

I'm a web developer building a stock trading app. Several times throughout the application there are occurrences of numbers with a percentage to show the difference between the last X period of time. They look like this:

£1.20 (+0.12%)

Or

(£0.50) (-0.60%)

All I've got at the moment is "diff" or "value and percentage", the latter of which is not particularly great.

Is there a specific name for this kind of value / structure when dealing with stock prices?

Comment: Context, please!

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the question with more context, please let me know if it's not enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called "change" or "movement" - the change (in points or percentage) from the last closing value.

You can [read more about the ticker tape on Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/01/070401.asp), the format you're referring to comes from there.

Comment: +1 - good answer, and why your score passed mine. I'd have closed this, glad you had the patience to answer it. Finance Vocabulary is important at any level.

Comment: Thankyou @littleadv, the extra link has been very helpful too.